# RequireJS and using this.id in a module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am switching an app over to RequireJS.

In my app, I detect when a user clicks on an element with a certain class on it.

I use the click event and this.id to get the unique id of the element.

Now that I've moved this function to a module for Require, I only get 'undefined' back for this.id.

I'm guessing the module doesn't have a reference for what was clicked when the function is called.

I also can't seem to pass this.id to the module.

> 'the use of a keyword as an identifier is invalid'.

So, how do I get the unique ID of the element clicked?

```
 $(document).on('click', '.userSelect', function (myID) {

    var retConvo = getConvoID.convoData();
    convoID = retConvo.convo;
    isGroup = retConvo.group;
    console.log("Conversation ID is: " + convoID + " and IsGroup: " + isGroup);
});
```

and here is the module code it's calling.

```
define(function() {

  return {
    convoData: function(myID) {
      var userSelected = this.id;
      console.log('User Selected ID is: ' + userSelected);
      if (userSelected == myID) {
        alert("You can't message yourself.");
        return false;
      } else {
        console.log("Selected User ID is: " + this.id);
        // change background to show user is selected.
        $("div.userSelected").removeClass("userSelected");
        $(this).addClass("userSelected");
        convoID = this.id;
        isGroup = 'N';
        console.log("emitting convo users id: " + convoID);
        return {
          convo: convoID,
          group: isGroup
        };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

So, when it get's to this.id above, it is undefined.  Worked fine when it was all in one js file.

Thanks for any help and pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. It doesn't seem like you're passing `myID` to the `convoData` function
2. `this` in the function refers to the local `this`. If you want it refer to the clicked element, either pass the element as a parameter to the function, or bind it at function call time: `var retConvo = getConvoID.convoData(myId).bind(this);`
   Alternatively, `var retConvo = getConvoID.convoData(myId, this);` and then change `convoData` to `function(myID, element)` and refer to `element.id`;
3. Use `===` instead of `==` in your code - has no bearing on this question per se, but will help you avoid problems down the line.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.  I trip myself up on seemingly simple things.